# How can I make a website link open NOT in the Telegram app's built-in browser?

Tags: javascript, telegram

I am developing a website. The problem is that when opening the website link from the mobile Telegram app, it opens in the app's built-in browser. This browser has its own limitations that are causing problems for me. How can I make the links open in the phone's default browser instead?

- adding `?target=_blank` at the end of url didn't fix this problem
- also try add this script in `index.html`

```html
<script>
    console.log("start")
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Telegram") != -1) {
        console.log("navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Telegram') != -1")
      window.location.replace("https://traffic-simulation.ru");
      console.log("window.location.replace('https://traffic-simulation.ru');")
    }
</script>
```

- also try to edit `.htaccess` file. It didn't help me

so how can I make a website link open **NOT** in the Telegram app's built-in browser?

Comment: What limitations do you hit? On recent Android versions, the embedded browser automatically uses the current Chrome engine.

Comment: Why are you outputting javascript code to the console? It will just print the code as a string if you wrap it in `"`. So instead of `console.log("navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Telegram') != -1")`, use `console.log(navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Telegram') != -1)` for example. What's the point of outputting that *within* the if statement? Put the console.log above so you can debug.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://telegram.org/js/telegram-web-app.js"></script> <button onclick="javascript:Telegram.WebApp.openLink('https://www.google.com/');">Click Me</button>
```

How I did it with a button.

https://github.com/telegram-mini-apps-dev/vanilla-js-boilerplate/tree/master